# Implicit functions of $f(x,y,z)= x \sin z- y \cos z=0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $U=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3} : x>0\}$ open and $f:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$f(x,y,z)= x \sin z- y \cos z.$$

1. Show that given $p=(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ if $f(p)=0$ then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(p)\neq 0$.
2. Let $V=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: x>0\}$ show that there are infinitely many continuous functions $g:V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x,y, g(x,y))=0$ for all $(x,y) \in V$, each $g$ is of class $\mathbb{C}^{\infty}$ and any two of them differ by a constant.

for the first part, we have $f(x,y,z)=x \sin z- y \cos z =0$, this is
$$\sin z=\frac{y \cos z}{x}.$$
Deriving we have
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=x \cos z+ y \sin z= x \cos z + y \sin z.$$
If we assume that $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=0$, we have
$$x \cos z + y \sin z=x \cos z + y \frac{y \cos z}{x}=\cos z (x^2+y^2)=0$$
as $x>0$, we have $\cos z=0$ then $z=\frac{(2n+1) \pi}{2}$, which is a contradiction because $x \sin z- y \cos z =0$.

I don't know how to demonstrate the second, any help please?

Answer (score 2):

For the first part I would start as you did, by calculating $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$, and then assume that bot that and $f(p)$ are zero at the same time (proof by contradiction). Then
$$x\sin z-y\cos z=0\\x\cos z+y\sin z=0$$
Square both equations and add them together. You get $$x^2+y^2=0$$
This is valid only when $x=y=0$. But you have $x>0$, so the hypothesis cannot happen.

For the second part let's explicitly find the formula for $g$:$$f(x,y,g(x,y))=0$$
$$x\sin(g(x,y))-y\cos(g(x,y))=0\\x\sin(g(x,y))=y\cos(g(x,y))$$
If $\cos(g(x,y))= 0$ then $\sin(g(x,y))=\pm1$, and the left hand side is non zero ($x>0)$. So $\cos(g(x,y))\ne 0$. Then we rewrite the last equation as
$$\tan g(x,y)=\frac yx$$ The solution for this equation are $$g(x,y)=\arctan\frac yx+n\pi$$